# Parsing a .xml document

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a `xml` file which contains cordinates of the bounding boxes of an image, consider the following-

```
<annotation>
    <path>C:\Test_Folder\testfile_1.jpg</path>
    <size>
        <width>1280</width>
        <height>720</height>
    </size>
    <object>
        <name>Bus</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>316</xmin>
            <ymin>232</ymin>
            <xmax>413</xmax>
            <ymax>403</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>595</xmin>
            <ymin>257</ymin>
            <xmax>962</xmax>
            <ymax>362</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I want to loop through all object tags and extract the object name and coordinates OR as a panda dataframe-

```
Bus, 316, 232, 413, 403
...
```

What I could write is the following and do not know how to proceed further.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
path = "C:\Test_Folder\testfile_1.xml"
etree = ET.parse(path) 
root = etree.getroot() 
for child in root:
    # don't know what next.
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should work

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''
<annotation>
    <path>C:\Test_Folder\testfile_1.jpg</path>
    <size>
        <width>1280</width>
        <height>720</height>
    </size>
    <object>
        <name>Bus</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>316</xmin>
            <ymin>232</ymin>
            <xmax>413</xmax>
            <ymax>403</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>Car</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>595</xmin>
            <ymin>257</ymin>
            <xmax>962</xmax>
            <ymax>362</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>'''

data = []
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for obj in root.findall('.//object'):
    data.append({'name': obj.find('name').text,
                 'xmin': obj.find('.//xmin').text,
                 'ymin': obj.find('.//ymin').text,
                 'xmax': obj.find('.//xmax').text,
                 'ymax': obj.find('.//ymax').text})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
  name xmin ymin xmax ymax
0  Bus  316  232  413  403
1  Car  595  257  962  362
```